# RGB LED Color Fading/Transition Libraries

Tags: colors, arduino, led, fastled

I'm looking for libraries of algorithms for color transitions over time. Somehow I haven't found the right search terms to find a library that would fit my needs, but writing everything from scratch feels silly. I've made good headway, but... reeeeally?

Here's some background...

My project has a handful of LEDs (well really, a handful light boxes, each with a pile of RGB LEDs inside), and I'd like to create a variety of color cycling patterns for the group of boxes. Some patterns would have all boxes cycle colors in sync. Some patterns might be start across the set.

In my implementation, each color cycling "pattern" would be defined by a series of colors and durations between each. At the end of the day, I'd have a variety of pattern concepts, like "fire" (red/yellow transitions with random flicker timing), "fireworks" (slow growing color to a frantic white flicker), etc.

The hardware driving the whole thing would be Arduinos + the FastLED library, so C code is ideal.

Hope this topic isn't outside of the StackOverflow Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're really looking for is an array of example code.  Ask on the FastLED g+ community (http://fastled.io/+) - a lot of folks on there will happily share sample code.  Also, look through the examples for FastLED itself.